# Can a processor do a for loop within 1 clock pulse?

Tags: verilog, computer-architecture

I am in a digital circuits class.  In this class we are using verilog to **simulate** (but not actually physically synthesize) different circuits. We have an assignment where we are supposed to simulate a circuit and one of the requirements makes it so there must be a for loop with a basic calculation in one clock pulse:

```
always@(posedge clock)
    for (i=0; i<11; i=i+1) begin
        if (i*i == data)
            isPerfectSquare = 1;
    end
```

What I am wondering is if this circuit is actually possible to implement in real hardware and not just simulate.  To me it seems impossible to fit an entire for loop within one clock pulse because a for loop would require registers that are updated ON the clock pulse.  The way I see it you would need at least 1 clock pulse per iteration.  Am I correct or is it actually possible to build a circuit that represents a for loop within a single clock pulse?

Comment: The loop is unrolled into a chain of comparators and multiplexers.

Comment: Always remember - it is a *hardware description language*, it is describing how the hardware should look, not what it should do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When verilog is synthesized, loops are unrolled.  So the code

```
always @(posedge clock) begin
    isPerfectSquare = 0;
    for (i=0; i<11; i=i+1) begin
        if (i*i == data)
            isPerfectSquare = 1;
    end
end
```

would be converted to

```
always @(posedge clock) begin
    isPerfectSquare = 0;
    if (0*0 == data)
        isPerfectSquare = 1;
    if (1*1 == data)
        isPerfectSquare = 1;
    if (2*2 == data)
        isPerfectSquare = 1;
    if (3*3 == data)
        isPerfectSquare = 1;
    if (4*4 == data)
        isPerfectSquare = 1;
    if (5*5 == data)
        isPerfectSquare = 1;
    if (6*6 == data)
        isPerfectSquare = 1;
    if (7*7 == data)
        isPerfectSquare = 1;
    if (8*8 == data)
        isPerfectSquare = 1;
    if (9*9 == data)
        isPerfectSquare = 1;
    if (10*10 == data)
        isPerfectSquare = 1;
end
```

which is then implemented as a bunch of N-bit comparators and a 10 input OR gate.

This is the ONLY way loops are handled in hardware description languages, including both verilog and VHDL.  The synthesizer must be able to unroll them.  Which means things like loop bounds must be determined at synthesis time - either as constants (such as in your question) or as parameters that are evaluated at synthesis time.

If you want to spread out execution across multiple clock cycles, then you have to implement your loop as an explicit state machine.

Answer (score 7):

In HDL the `for` loop *is not* something the hardware is *executing*. It is something the synthesis tool is generating. In your case it will just become a bunch of comparators (11 of them) or similar hardware with the input of `data` and squared numbers  from `0` to `10^2`. And something like an `OR` gate on their outputs with an output `isPerfectSquare`.

Answer (score 2):

Before I get on to your main question there are a couple of issues I see with your code.

1. You never initialise "isPerfectSquare".
2. If you use "blocking assignments" within a sequential always block you should only read the result in the same always block. Reading them from other always blocks can lead to unpredictable behaviour and/or differences between synthisis and simulation.

In particular the first of these issues may well mean that the synthesis tool simplifies your code to something like.

```
assign isPerfectSquare = 1;
```

So lets consider a fixed version of your code so we can get on to your main question.

```
always@(posedge clock) begin
    isPerfectSquareInternal = 0
    for (i=0; i<11; i=i+1) begin
        if (i*i == data)
            isPerfectSquareInternal = 1;
    end
    isPerfectSquare <= isPerfectSquareInternal
end
```

Now lets play synthesis tool and see if we can turn this into combinatorial logic feeding a final register.

In general we can turn an "if statement" into a multiplexer, but in this particular case we can go one better and turn it into a logical or operation.

```
always@(posedge clock) begin
    isPerfectSquareInternal = 0
    for (i=0; i<11; i=i+1) begin
        isPerfectSquareInternal = isPerfectSquareInternal || (i*i == data)
    end
    isPerfectSquare <= isPerfectSquareInternal
end
```

Now for dealing with the for loop. We note that the loop has a fixed number of iterations, therefore we can unroll it.

```
always@(posedge clock) begin
    isPerfectSquareInternal0 = (0 == data)
    isPerfectSquareInternal1 = isPerfectSquareInternal0 || (1 == data)
    isPerfectSquareInternal2 = isPerfectSquareInternal1 || (4 == data)
    isPerfectSquareInternal3 = isPerfectSquareInternal2 || (9 == data)
    isPerfectSquareInternal4 = isPerfectSquareInternal3 || (16 == data)
    isPerfectSquareInternal5 = isPerfectSquareInternal4 || (25 == data)
    isPerfectSquareInternal6 = isPerfectSquareInternal5 || (36 == data)
    isPerfectSquareInternal7 = isPerfectSquareInternal6 || (49 == data)
    isPerfectSquareInternal8 = isPerfectSquareInternal7 || (64 == data)
    isPerfectSquareInternal9 = isPerfectSquareInternal8 || (81 == data)
    isPerfectSquareInternal10 = isPerfectSquareInternal9 || (100 == data)
    isPerfectSquare <= isPerfectSquareInternal10
end
```